# Fraction field and ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and let $O$ be a subring of the ring of integers $O_K$ of $K$.
Show that $O$ contains a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $K$ if and only if the field of fractions of $O$ is $K$.

I proved the "only if" part.

Now for the "if" part I have a hint: Show that it makes sense to talk about the largest subfield $K_0$ of $K$ such that $O$ contains a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $K_0$. Then assume for contradiction that $K_0 \neq K$.

Clearly $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of $K$ and $O$ contains a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of it (namely $1$). So it has sense to talk about the largest subfield of $K$ satisfying this condition. I have two main ideas:

$1$) Since $K_0 \neq K$ there exists $\alpha \in K-K_0$. I can write $\alpha=\frac{\beta}{\gamma}$ for some $\beta, \gamma \neq 0 \in O$ since $K$ is the field of fractions of $O$. Now I would like to write $\alpha$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of the basis but I don't know how to proceed.

$2$) Since $K$ is the minimal subfield in which $O$ can be embedded (by definition of field of fractions), then $O$ is not contained in $K_0$ and thus there exists $\alpha \in O-K_0$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You know $\mathbb{Q}O_L=\bigcup_n \frac1nO_L=L$ for any number field $L$ (Recall the usual proof: for $\alpha\in L$ look at the minimal polynomial $f(X)=a_dX^d+a_{d-1}X^{d-1}+\dots+a_0\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ of $\alpha$.  Then $a_d\alpha\in O_L$ since it satisfies $(a_d\alpha)^d+a_{d-1}a_d(a_d\alpha)^{d-1}+\dots+a_0a_d^d=0$.).  With the same notation we have $\alpha^{-1}\in a_0^{-1} O\subseteq\mathbb{Q}O$ (for $0\neq\alpha\in O$) since $a_0\alpha^{-1}=-a_1-a_2\alpha-\dots-a_d\alpha^{d-1}\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\subseteq O$.
Hence $O\subseteq K_0$ gives $K=\mathbb{Q}O\subseteq K_0$, which is only possible if $K_0=K$.

Comment: The first equality is a restatement of what is asked to prove.

Comment: I assumed the OP has seen that before and just a problem of translating that to another description, and no it isn't a restatement of the problem because our $O$ need not be integrally closed.  Anyway, a sketch of proof is now given.

Comment: But if $K_0 \neq K=\mathrm{Frac}(O)$ then $O  \not \subseteq K_O$ by minimality of $K$

Comment: There is no need to assume $K_0\neq K$.  $K_0\subseteq K$ exists, and we just need to prove it contains all elements of $K$, which is what we did here.  Of course adding the artificial $K_0\neq K$ changes it from a direct proof to a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Still I don't get your proof. You say $\mathbb{Q}O_L=L$ for any number field $L$, but then you use $K=\mathbb{Q}O$ and $O \subseteq O_K$

Comment: With the same proof, $\mathbb{Q}O$ contains the inverse of every nonzero element of $O$, so $\mathbb{Q}O=\operatorname{Frac}O=K$.

Comment: Who guarantees me that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \subseteq O$? You proved that for every algebraic number there exists $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, but you don't know a priori if $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \subseteq O$

Comment: $O$ is a ring because it is given as a subring of $O_K$, and $\alpha\in O$.

Comment: Ok, it's a ring, but why should it contain $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$???

Comment: $O$ must contain $1\in O_K$ and hence contains $\mathbb{Z}$.  It also contains $\alpha$.  Hence it contains all $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ because $O$ is closed under multiplication and addition.